# What is the recommended indentation style for OpenMP clauses?

Tags: openmp, pragma

OpenMP clauses and brackets could exists same time in code. Is there any regulation of coding style about nested OpenMp clauses?

e.g:

```
#pragma omp parallel
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  code1();
# pragma omp for // Should this line be intended?
  for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
  code2();
#   pragma omp critical { 
    code3(); // Should this block and brackets be intended?
    }
  }
  code4();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From an OpenMP perspective there's no real guideline about how to indent the code.

The way I write the code would look like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  code1();
#pragma omp for // Should this line be intended?
  for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
    code2();
#pragma omp critical 
    { // this curly brace needs to go on its own  line
      code3(); // Should this block and brackets be intended?
    }
  }
  code4();
}
```

So, the pragmas start in the first column and the base language code follows whatever style you are using.  The rational is that if you deleted all OpenMP pragmas you still get "pretty" base language code.

I seem to also recall that compiler pragmas have to have their '#' in the first column.  I'll leave it other to correct my memory on this, as I'm not sure about if ISO C/C++ actually requires it.  I haven't seen any compiler lately, that would enforce it.